# Why am I unable to map my data in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jsx

Ill be changing the key shortly. Using the code below I should be able to load a list of movies from the API and each movie should be linked to it's Provider Link website.  using
the upMovieDetail.   can anyone help point me in the right direction?  I have a feeling it has something to do with the component being re-renderd after the click?

here is the codesandbox if you'd rather try to fix it here.. --
https://codesandbox.io/s/movieapp-searchbar-forked-qv1o6

````
const key ="fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95";

const getUpMovieDetail = (movieId) => {
     //const [movieId, setMovieId] = useState([]);

    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}/watch/providers?api_key=${key}`;
        return fetch(url);
      };
      
      function UpMovieDetail({ movieItem }) {
        const [searchLink, setSearchLink] = useState(null);
      
        useEffect(() => {
          getUpMovieDetail(movieItem.id)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
              setSearchLink(res?.results?.US?.link);
            });
        }, [movieItem.id]);

        return (
            <ul className="flexed-search">
    {searchLink.map((item) => 
    <div className="poster-container" key={item.id}>
    <li className="list-item">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={searchLink}
        onclick={((event) => {event.preventDefault()})}>
     <img className="image-element"  tabIndex="0" alt="movie poster" 
     title={`--Title: ${item.title}--  --Description:    
     ${item.overview}--  --Vote Average: ${item.vote_average}`} 
     aria-label={item.title} 
     src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${item.poster_path}`} />
     </a>
    <h3 className="posterTitle">{item.title}</h3>
    </li>
    </div>
 )}
</ul>
          );
        }; 


const SearchBar = () => {

const [search, setSearch] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
 

// Input Field
const onUserInput = ({target}) => {
    setInput(target.value);

};



//  Api Call 
const SearchApi = (event) => {
    const aUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95";
   const newUrl = aUrl +'&query=' + input;
 event.preventDefault();
       
    fetch(newUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
       setSearch(data.results);
        
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error!! Data interupted!:', error)
    })

    };
    
      return (
        //   Heading
<div>
    <div className="container">
        <h1>Movie Search Extravaganza!</h1>
       {/* Input Field and Button Form */}
      <form onSubmit={SearchApi}>
        <input value={input} onChange={onUserInput} type="text"  className="searchbar" aria-label="searchbar" placeholder="search" required/>
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit"  aria-label="searchbutton" className="searchBtn">Movie Express Search</button>
      </form>
      <h1 className="row-label" tabIndex="0">Movies Related To Your Search</h1>
     </div>

 <div className="byName-container">
  {search.map((item) => (
    <UpMovieDetail key={item.id} movieItem={item} />
  ))}
</div>
 
 </div>
      )};

export default SearchBar;```


  [1]: http://codesandbox.io/s/movieapp-searchbar-forked-qv1o6
  [2]: https://codesandbox.io/s/movieapp-searchbar-forked-qv1o6
````

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working? What do you expect to see vs what you're actually seeing?

Comment: Hooks like `useState()` must be declared at top level of the component, not inside other functions. For array data to be fetched asynchronously if useState doesn't have an empty array as default the first render will try to do `undefined.map()` and throw error

Comment: @Phil so whats happening is when I enter a movie into the search bar Im supposed to get a list of 20 movies rendered to me.  Each movie is an image with a title and each movie image is also a link which when clicked takes you to a website where you can watch the movie.  What Im getting is searchLink.map is not a function error.  Basically...I want what I did here...https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bardeen-hwvhb  but the one im working on now needs to be hooked up to an onClick event and the APi is searched when the search button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

From the first render it throws the error because `searchLink` is `null`.
Try this:

```
{
  searchLink && searchLink.length && searchLink.map((item) =>
  ...
}
```